# Is there a way to change what happens after you save a new entry?

Tags: entries, admin, saving

I want to remain on the page I just saved so I can view it in the browser and return to continue editing, without having to find the page again in the all pages/entries area.

Is there a way to change the Craft CMS defaults on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, and it's easy!

The "Save" button contains a dropdown arrow, with alternative options for saving:

[image: Save options]

You'll notice that "Save and continue editing" is the top option. You may also notice that there's a keyboard shortcut for it... `cmd + s` on Mac, `ctrl + s` on PC.